# Inserting a full-size HTML page into a confluence page (in this case a gitgraph page)

Tags: html, confluence

I'm writing a documentation for my codebase in Confluence and I want to add dynamically generated gitgraphs (https://gitgraphjs.com/).

Doing it with images is obviously possible, but I'd like to insert the HTML instead so that modifications can be done directly in the confluence page.

I've managed to use 'HTML Macro' to insert the HTML code, but it only renders as a tiny square inside the confluence page.

I tried fiddling around with CSS and tried to backwards-engineer the classes that Confluence was using, without success. I'm using Confluence 6.13.10

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

What do you use within the `HTML` macro? An `<iframe>`?

If `iframe` is used, then pass it some parameters:

```
<iframe src="https://gitgraphjs.com/..." frameborder=0 width="100%" height="1080px" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Comment: Hi, no i'm not doing an iframe - I want all the HTML code to be directly editable. I'm using a div as a container.

Comment: And how do you insert the external HTML content with HTML macro then?

Comment: I've setup the page separately, I'm just pasting what's between the <body> tags into the space

Comment: I still don't understand. Where is the source stored you embed to Confluence? On gitgraphjs.com? Could you add screenshots of the problem (page in view mode, page in edit mode and the storage format) into the OP?

Comment: I'm writing the file myself, it's a local file, and I'm copying the HTML from one file directly into confluence

Comment: Do you mean directly into Confluence as a separate file (attachment)? So you need to read and render the attached HTML file content? This is quite difficult. I would rather write the HTML content directly to the Confluence page using REST API or have all graphs stored on a different server and embed them into Confluence.